# ionic $stateprovider showing blank page on device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

why this sample code http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/QwamEW is working on browser but show blank page when i test on ios simulator or device ?

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
        url: '/event',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/event-menu.html'
    })
    .state('eventmenu.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.checkin', {
        url: '/check-in',
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: 'templates/check-in.html',
                controller: 'CheckinCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.attendees', {
        url: '/attendees',
        views: {
            'menuContent' :{
                templateUrl: 'templates/attendees.html',
                controller: 'AttendeesCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/event/home');
})
```

Comment: how are you deploying it to a device ?

Comment: using ionic cli ionic build ios, then i run the xcode project

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?